# How to use Poiters (References) in a VBA For Each Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the following code the source `etapasArray` doesn't have their own values changed!

The array `etapasArray` has each element accessed as `etapasArray(i)(j)`.

This is the sub function:

```vb
'etapasArray is accessed as etapasArray(i)(j) and etapaRow was declared as Variant
Public Sub setDatasPLANO()
    For Each etapaRow In etapasArray
        If etapaRow(oFolhaPlaneamento.positionElement("PERCENTAGEM")) < 1 Then
            etapaRow(oFolhaPlaneamento.positionElement("PLANO_INICIO")) = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It reads correctly the existing values but the final `etapasArray` never gets the number 1 in it! Any ideas?

Comment: `etapasArray(i)(j)` means you have a jagged array, not a 2D array. `etapaRow` contains a copy of the inner array at `i`. When you write to it, you write to the copy, not to the original array. If you want to update the original array, you need to `etapasArray(i) = etapaRow` after you have updated `etapaRow`. For that purpose you want the `i`, which you can have if you enumerate the array using `For` and not `For Each`.

Answer (score 1):

you are not writing anything to the etapasArray in that code, are you? Did you wanna do:

```
etapasArray(oFolhaPlaneamento.positionElement("PLANO_INICIO")) = 1
```

Instead of

```
etapaRow(oFolhaPlaneamento.positionElement("PLANO_INICIO")) = 1
```

If not, then I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: `Did you wanna do:` - no, they wanted `etapasArray(i) = etapaRow`, except that they don't currently have the `i`.

Comment: Ahh makes sense now! Thanks